# php file not called from ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

Have a problem to call my server.php to add some values into db.
server.php:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','user','password');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name,email,phone,address) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$email);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$phone);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$address);
$stmt->execute();

echo "data saved";
?>
```

Calling the server.php directly, the data will be saved.
But from my Html/Ajax code it will not:

```
<script>
function saveData(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server.php",
        data: "name=" +name+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&address="+address,
    }).done(function(data){
        alert('success');
        $('#result').html("<br/><div> class='alert alert-info'>" + data +"</div>");
    )};

    return false;
</script>
```

The alert('success') won't be called also #result div isn't filled.
Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: any error showing in console ?

Comment: nothing is displayed in console except the bootstrap css warnings and some other js stuff.

Comment: how are you triggering the saveData function, you're also missing a closing `}` after your `return false;`, so at the least you should have a syntax error in your console?

Comment: You are right, the `}` was missing, but this doesn't fix the problem. The `saveData()` Function is triggered from a form by a `onclick` event on a button.

Comment: Your gonna have to use your console friend, you should see the outgoing request being made and any errors / response should be shown too

Comment: You've also mixed up `)` and `}` at the end of `done` callback.

Comment: _"and some other js stuff"_ - that might be important!?

Comment: Mixing of `)` and `}` is fixed. Thanks for that hint. JS Errors are not in reference with my scripting. It is referenced to jquery-latest.js

Comment: Need some more detailed info which is not apparent in the question: 1) check that the onclick event is definitely working - a simple `console.log` call just inside the saveData function can verify this. 2) If that's working, check the network tab in the browser. See what's being submitted to the server, and what the HTTP status coming back is. If the status returned is not "200" then the ".done" method will not fire (you need to implement ".fail()" to handle errors, see the jQuery ajax and Deferred documentation).

Comment: Also, I would not hand-code your querystring like that, it's brittle and prone to encoding errors. Instead specify `data` as an object, and jQuery will correctly serialise it into the request for you: e.g. `data: { "name": name, "email": email, "phone": phone, "address": address }`

Comment: So, i fixed. Changed from  `function saveData(){` to a jquery click handler `$("#save_button").click(function(){` and gave the button an id. Now it works.